# applicaion/Json converting to text/plain inside MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: jersey, httpclient, multipart

Trying to hit jersey multipart service with httpclient, type application/json getting converted to text/plain and service failing to recognize. Thanks for your inputs.

```
entitybuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entitybuilder.addBinaryBody("image", inputStream, ContentType.create(CONTENT_TYPE), "file name");
    entitybuilder.addPart("json", new StringBody(requestBodyJson, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked.

```
    entitybuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
    entitybuilder.addBinaryBody("image", inputStream, ContentType.create(CONTENT_TYPE), "file name");
        entitybuilder.addTextBody("json", requestBodyJson,  ContentType.create(APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Please go through this link for more details.
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/377